# Reading a single char in Java

Tags: java

How can a char be entered in Java from keyboard?

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811851/how-do-i-read-input-character-by-character-in-java

Comment: why do you start every question name with "question about"? This is redundant.

Comment: read a char without waiting a carriage return: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62122059/in-java-is-it-possible-to-system-in-read-reads-a-key-without-waiting-a-carriage

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can either scan an entire line:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = s.nextLine();
```

Or you can read a single `char`, given you know what encoding you're dealing with:

```
char c = (char) System.in.read();
```

Comment: `char c = (char) System.in.read();` (casting a byte from system encoding to UTF-16) will only work if the characters have identical values in both encodings; this will usually only work for a very small range of characters. Using `Scanner` is more reliable.

Comment: `System.in.read()` may block until the user types a carriage return (at least on Windows)

Comment: `System.in.read()` block until the user types return in Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 19):

You can use Scanner like so:

```
Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
char x = s.next().charAt(0);
```

By using the charAt function you are able to get the value of the first char without using external casting.

Comment: This has the same problem as the accepted answer: it will block until the user types the carriage return (at least on Windows)

Comment: it blocks until the user types return in Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 8):

Using nextline and System.in.read as often proposed requires the user to hit enter after typing a character. However, people searching for an answer to this question, may also be interested in directly respond to a key press in a console!

I found a solution to do so using [jline3](https://github.com/jline/jline3), wherein we first change the terminal into rawmode to directly respond to keys, and then wait for the next entered character:

```java
var terminal = TerminalBuilder.terminal()
terminal.enterRawMode()
var reader = terminal.reader()

var c = reader.read()
```

```java
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jline</groupId>
    <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great answer. Maven Central Repo <dependency>
    <groupId>jline</groupId>
    <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Still requires a enter stroke though.

Comment: I used this to respond to the keys 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' to navigate left right up down. No need to press enter.

Comment: Did you by any chance write out something in between and flush the buffer?

Comment: Does that make a difference? Interesting! Yes, I basically reprinted the whole screen (width x height) :)

Comment: I tried version 3.23.0 and it works great with Linux (didn't try Windows or MacOS); grabs single character, no Enter/Return key needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for this. It's not clear what your exact requirements are, but here's an example that should be illustrative:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s*");
    while (!sc.hasNext("z")) {
        char ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.print("[" + ch + "] ");
    }
```

If you give this input:

```
123 a b c x   y   z
```

The output is:

```
[1] [2] [3] [a] [b] [c] [x] [y]
```

So what happens here is that the `Scanner` uses `\s*` as delimiter, which is the regex for "zero or more whitespace characters". This skips spaces etc in the input, so you only get non-whitespace characters, one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

i found this way worked nice:

```
    {
    char [] a;
    String temp;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please give the first integer :");
    temp=keyboard.next();
    a=temp.toCharArray();
    }
```

you can also get individual one with String.charAt()

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class 'getJ' with a static function 'chr()'.  This function reads one char.

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

class getJ {
    static char  chr()throws IOException{  
        BufferedReader bufferReader =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return bufferReader.readLine().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

In order to read a char use this:

```
anyFunc()throws IOException{
...
...
char c=getJ.chr();
}
```

Because of 'chr()' is static, you don't have to create  'getJ' by 'new' ;   I mean
you don't need to do:

```
getJ ob = new getJ;
c=ob.chr();
```

You should remember to add 'throws IOException' to the function's head.       If it's impossible, use try / catch  as follows:

```
anyFunc(){// if it's impossible to add 'throws IOException' here
...
try
{
char c=getJ.chr(); //reads a char into c
} 
catch(IOException e)
{
System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
}
```

Credit to:
[tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-scanner-and-bufferreader-class-in-java#:~:text=During%20multithreading%20environment%2C%20BufferReader%20should%20be%20used.&text=Scanner%20has%20little%20buffer%20of,Buffer%20as%20compared%20to%20Scanner.&text=Scanner%20is%20bit%20slower%20as%20it%20need%20to%20parse%20data%20as%20well.)

See also: [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-scanner-and-bufferreader-class-in-java/#:~:text=The%20Scanner%20has%20a%20little,simply%20reads%20sequence%20of%20characters.).

[java](/questions/tagged/java) [bufferedreader](/questions/tagged/bufferedreader) [input](/questions/tagged/input) [getchar](/questions/tagged/getchar) [char](/questions/tagged/char)

Answer (score 0):

In order to read a character at a time from a JVM run from the console, you need to turn off line-buffering on stdin. Here's a shell script to do that:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
save_state=$(stty -g)
stty cbreak  # set "control-break" mode
stty -echo   # disable echo

/usr/bin/java SomeTest
stty "$save_state"
```

Answer (score -1):

....
char ch;
...
ch=scan.next().charAt(0);
.
.
It's the easy way to get character.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could try this code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
  {
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String userInput = in.readLine();
  System.out.println("\n\nUser entered -> " + userInput);
  }
  catch(IOException e)
  {
  System.out.println("IOException has been caught");
  }
 }
}
```