# Validating input using java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I'm taking user input from `System.in` using a `java.util.Scanner`. I need to validate the input for things like:

- It must be a non-negative number
- It must be an alphabetical letter
- ... etc

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Many of your questions are in a form like this: badly worded pleas for someone else to post code without you showing what your have done (or tried) yourself. This is not the way to learn new things. Get your hand dirty! Try a couple of things yourself and, when getting stuck somewhere, post a specific question here (and post the code that didn't work). I assure you that by doing so, you will receive better responses than these close-votes.

Comment: @Bart K: would it be fair to other answerers if, in an effort to improve the question to make it worthy of reopening, I edit it to ask how to validate inputs using `Scanner`? Based on OP's previous Q, it seems that `Scanner` is what OP is working with.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, yes, I'd vote to re-open if the question would be rephrased so that it made more sense. It would be a shame if this question would get deleted in the long run (and all good answer with it (mainly yours)). Of course, I had hoped @bhavna would have tried to improve it him- or herself...

Comment: @Bart K: edit done. Will also improve my answer even further. Apologies to the other answerers if they feel that this was unfair.

Comment: It's unbelievable that this question had already collected 2 delete votes. Reopened.

Answer (score 167):

#### Overview of `Scanner.hasNextXXX` methods

[`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has many `hasNextXXX` methods that can be used to validate input. Here's a brief overview of all of them:

- [`hasNext()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) - does it have *any* token at all?
- [`hasNextLine()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine%28%29) - does it have another line of input?
- For Java primitives

  - [`hasNextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) - does it have a token that can be parsed into an `int`?
  - Also available are [`hasNextDouble()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29), [`hasNextFloat()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat%28%29), [`hasNextByte()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextByte%28%29), [`hasNextShort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextShort%28%29), [`hasNextLong()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLong%28%29), and [`hasNextBoolean()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBoolean%28%29)
  - As bonus, there's also [`hasNextBigInteger()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigInteger%28%29) and [`hasNextBigDecimal()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextBigDecimal%28%29)
  - The integral types also has overloads to specify radix (for e.g. hexadecimal)
- Regular expression-based

  - [`hasNext(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29)
  - [`hasNext(Pattern pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) is the [`Pattern.compile`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile%28java.lang.String%29) overload

`Scanner` is capable of more, enabled by the fact that it's regex-based. One important feature is [`useDelimiter(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29), which lets you define what *pattern* separates your tokens. There are also `find` and `skip` methods that *ignores* delimiters.

The following discussion will keep the regex as simple as possible, so the focus remains on `Scanner`.

---

#### Example 1: Validating positive ints

Here's a simple example of using `hasNextInt()` to validate positive `int` from the input.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
```

Here's an example session:

> ***Please enter a positive number!***
>   five
>   ***That's not a number!***
>   -3
>   ***Please enter a positive number!***
>   5
>   ***Thank you! Got 5***

Note how much easier `Scanner.hasNextInt()` is to use compared to the more verbose `try/catch` [`Integer.parseInt`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)/[`NumberFormatException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) combo. By contract, a `Scanner` *guarantees* that if it `hasNextInt()`, then `nextInt()` will peacefully give you that `int`, and will *not* throw any `NumberFormatException`/`InputMismatchException`/`NoSuchElementException`.

#### Related questions

- [How to use Scanner to accept only valid int as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912817/how-to-use-scanner-to-accept-only-valid-int-as-input)
- [How do I keep a scanner from throwing exceptions when the wrong type is entered? (java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496239/how-do-i-keep-a-scanner-from-throwing-exceptions-when-the-wrong-type-is-entered)

---

#### Example 2: Multiple `hasNextXXX` on the same token

Note that the snippet above contains a `sc.next()` statement to advance the `Scanner` until it `hasNextInt()`. It's important to realize that ***none* of the** `hasNextXXX` **methods advance the** `Scanner` **past any input!** You will find that if you omit this line from the snippet, then it'd go into an infinite loop on an invalid input!

This has two consequences:

- If you need to skip the "garbage" input that fails your `hasNextXXX` test, then you need to advance the `Scanner` one way or another (e.g. `next()`, `nextLine()`, `skip`, etc).
- If one `hasNextXXX` test fails, you can *still* test if it perhaps `hasNextYYY`!

Here's an example of performing multiple `hasNextXXX` tests.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (!sc.hasNext("exit")) {
    System.out.println(
        sc.hasNextInt() ? "(int) " + sc.nextInt() :
        sc.hasNextLong() ? "(long) " + sc.nextLong() :  
        sc.hasNextDouble() ? "(double) " + sc.nextDouble() :
        sc.hasNextBoolean() ? "(boolean) " + sc.nextBoolean() :
        "(String) " + sc.next()
    );
}
```

Here's an example session:

> 5
>   ***(int) 5***
>   false
>   ***(boolean) false***
>   blah
>   ***(String) blah***
>   1.1
>   ***(double) 1.1***
>   100000000000
>   ***(long) 100000000000***
>   exit

Note that the order of the tests matters. If a `Scanner` `hasNextInt()`, then it also `hasNextLong()`, but it's not necessarily `true` the other way around. More often than not you'd want to do the more specific test before the more general test.

---

#### Example 3 : Validating vowels

`Scanner` has many advanced features supported by regular expressions. Here's an example of using it to validate vowels.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a vowel, lowercase!");
while (!sc.hasNext("[aeiou]")) {
    System.out.println("That's not a vowel!");
    sc.next();
}
String vowel = sc.next();
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + vowel);
```

Here's an example session:

> ***Please enter a vowel, lowercase!***
>   5
>   ***That's not a vowel!***
>   z
>   ***That's not a vowel!***
>   e
>   ***Thank you! Got e***

In regex, as a Java string literal, the pattern `"[aeiou]"` is what is called a "character class"; it matches any of the letters `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, `u`. Note that it's trivial to make the above test case-insensitive: just provide such regex pattern to the `Scanner`.

#### API links

- [`hasNext(String pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) - Returns `true` if the next token matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.
- [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

#### Related questions

- [Reading a single char in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043306/reading-a-single-char-in-java/)

#### References

- [Java Tutorials/Essential Classes/Regular Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- [regular-expressions.info/Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

---

#### Example 4: Using two `Scanner` at once

Sometimes you need to scan line-by-line, with multiple tokens on a line. The easiest way to accomplish this is to use *two* `Scanner`, where the second `Scanner` takes the `nextLine()` from the first `Scanner` as input. Here's an example:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Give me a bunch of numbers in a line (or 'exit')");
while (!sc.hasNext("exit")) {
    Scanner lineSc = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
    int sum = 0;
    while (lineSc.hasNextInt()) {
        sum += lineSc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
}
```

Here's an example session:

> ***Give me a bunch of numbers in a line (or 'exit')***
>   3 4 5
>   ***Sum is 12***
>   10 100 a million dollar
>   ***Sum is 110***
>   wait what?
>   ***Sum is 0***
>   exit

In addition to [`Scanner(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) constructor, there's also [`Scanner(java.io.File)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) among others.

---

#### Summary

- `Scanner` provides a rich set of features, such as `hasNextXXX` methods for validation.
- Proper usage of `hasNextXXX/nextXXX` in combination means that a `Scanner` will **NEVER** throw an `InputMismatchException`/`NoSuchElementException`.
- Always remember that `hasNextXXX` does not advance the `Scanner` past any input.
- Don't be shy to create multiple `Scanner` if necessary. Two simple `Scanner` is often better than one overly complex `Scanner`.
- Finally, even if you don't have any plans to use the advanced regex features, do keep in mind which methods are regex-based and which aren't. Any `Scanner` method that takes a `String pattern` argument is regex-based.

  - *Tip*: an easy way to turn any `String` into a literal pattern is to [`Pattern.quote`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) it.

Comment: this code is working for negative numbers but not for alphabet

Comment: That's probably the best way yo go about it, depending on the input method, of course.

Comment: @bhavna: learn from the code and do the rest yourself.

Comment: @bhavna, please stop expecting others to do all **your** work. Also, thanking someone from time to time wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: I love hasNextInt(). Ive been dealing with NumberFormatException cuz i didn't read doc enough. ouch. thanks for the information. very nice example too.

Comment: what is the importance of sc.next() in the first example that you gave?

Answer (score 9):

Here's a minimalist way to do it.

```
System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");
while(!scan.hasNextInt()) scan.next();
int demoInt = scan.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 3):

For checking Strings for letters you can use regular expressions for example:

```
someString.matches("[A-F]");
```

For checking numbers and stopping the program crashing, I have a quite simple class you can find below where you can define the range of values you want.
[Here](http://computersciencecs.blogspot.dk/2012/12/java-input-checking.html)

```
    public int readInt(String prompt, int min, int max)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;

    //Run once and loop until the input is within the specified range.
    do 
    {
        //Print users message.
        System.out.printf("\n%s > ", prompt);

        //Prevent string input crashing the program.
        while (!scan.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            System.out.printf("Input doesn't match specifications. Try again.");
            System.out.printf("\n%s > ", prompt);
            scan.next(); 
        }

        //Set the number.
        number = scan.nextInt();

        //If the number is outside range print an error message.
        if (number < min || number > max)
            System.out.printf("Input doesn't match specifications. Try again.");

    } while (number < min || number > max);

    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea:

```
try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(myString);
    if (i < 0) {
        // Error, negative input
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Error, not a number.
}
```

There is also, in [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang) library the [CharUtils](http://api/org/apache/commons/lang3/CharUtils.html) class that provides the methods `isAsciiNumeric()` to check that a character is a number, and `isAsciiAlpha()` to check that the character is a letter...

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing string data from the console or similar, the best way is to use regular expressions. Read more on that here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/1.4regex/

Otherwise, to parse an int from a string, try
[Integer.parseInt(string)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). If the string is not a number, you will get an exception. Otherise you can then perform your checks on that value to make sure it is not negative.

```
String input;
int number;
try
{
    number = Integer.parseInt(input);
    if(number > 0)
    {
        System.out.println("You positive number is " + number);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException ex)
{
     System.out.println("That is not a positive number!");
}
```

To get a character-only string, you would probably be better of looping over each character checking for digits, using for instance [Character.isLetter(char)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

```
String input
for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++)
{
   if(!Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i)))
   {
      System.out.println("This string does not contain only letters!");
      break;
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

what i have tried is that first i took the integer input and checked that whether its is negative or not if its negative then again take the input

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    int a=s.nextInt();
    while(a<0)
    {
    System.out.println("please provide non negative integer input ");
    a=s.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("the non negative integer input is "+a);
```

Here, you need to take the character input first and check whether user gave character or not if not than again take the character input

```
    char ch = s.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    while(!Charcter.isLetter(ch))
    {
    System.out.println("please provide a character input ");
    ch=s.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    }
    System.out.println("the character  input is "+ch);
```

Comment: do more than posting some code. Explain WHY that code is the answer to the question. Especially 7 years after the initial question.

Comment: i just want to add my observation ..if any people will come here he will see for solutions...he will not see the timings...just like that i came here...you need to understand my code ...that what i have tried is that first i took the integer input and checked that whether its is negative or not if its negative than again take the input thats it and the second part is you need to take the character input first and check whether user gave character or not if not than again take the character input