# Whats the best way to parse a file in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file with Tag - Value format data. I want to parse this file to form a Trie. What will be the best approach?

Sample of File: (String inside "" is a tag and '#' is used to comment the line.)

```
 #Hi, this is a sample file.

"abcd" = 12;
"abcde" = 16;
"http" = 32;
"sip" = 21;
```

Comment: What is a Trie? if you mean Tree, this data is not in a tree structure. Homework tag?

Comment: [This is a trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @Byron A Trie is a data structure similar to a Tree. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @Hank Thank you. Ive not heard of that data structer before.

Comment: @Byron It's somewhat obscure. I don't think I've seen one "in the wild" because they aren't really targeted at my domain.

Comment: Here's a Trie in Java: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5295936

Comment: @dsmsith, @Tedil, @Hank, SO does it again. Thank you for the info!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this; others have mentioned that [`java.util.Properties`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) gets most of the job done, and is probably the most robust solution.

One other option is to use a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

- Use the [`Scanner(File)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) constructor to scan a file
- You can [`useDelimiter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) appropriate for this format
- [`nextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) can be used to extract the numbers
- Perhaps you can put the key/value pairs into a [`SortedMap<String,Integer>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)

Here's an example that scans a `String` for simplicity:

```
    String text =
        "#Hi, this is a sample file.\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\"abcd\" = 12; \r\n" +
        "\"abcde\"=16;\n" + 
        "  # \"ignore\" = 13;\n" +
        "\"http\" = 32;  # Comment here \r" + 
        "\"zzz\" = 666;  # Out of order! \r" + 
        "   \"sip\"  =  21 ;";

    System.out.println(text);
    System.out.println("----------");

    SortedMap<String,Integer> map = new TreeMap<String,Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(text).useDelimiter("[\"=; ]+");
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        if (sc.hasNext("[a-z]+")) {
            map.put(sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
        }
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

This prints ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/A7tOP)):

```
#Hi, this is a sample file.

"abcd" = 12; 
"abcde"=16;
  # "ignore" = 13;
"http" = 32;  # Comment here 
"zzz" = 666;  # Out of order! 
   "sip"  =  21 ;
----------
{abcd=12, abcde=16, http=32, sip=21, zzz=666}
```

#### Related questions

- [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner/)
- [Iterate Over Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-map)

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 5):

Read that in using [Properties](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and trim the excess parts (`"`, `;` and whitespace). Short example:

```
Properties props = Properties.load(this.getClass()
                                       .getResourceAsStream("path/to.file"));
Map<String, String> cleanedProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
for(Entry pair : props.entrySet()) {
    cleanedProps.put(cleanKey(pair.getKey()),
                     cleanValue(pair.getValue()));
}
```

Note that in the solution above you only need implement the `cleanKey()` and `cleanValue()` yourself. You may want to change the datatypes accordingly if necessary, I used Strings just as an example.

Comment: Or simplify the source file so it doesn't have these extra characters. ;)

Comment: He gave us the input to work with, I'm just working with what I got.

Answer (score 5):

This is basically a properties file, I would remove the " around the tags, then use the Properties class http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader) to load the file.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me with this new Class.

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way is probably this:

```
void doParse() {
        String text =
                "#Hi, this is a sample file.\n"
                + "\"abcd\" = 12;\n"
                + "\"abcde\" = 16;\n"
                + "#More comment\n"
                + "\"http\" = 32;\n"
                + "\"sip\" = 21;";

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\"(.+)\" = ([0-9]+)").matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String txt = matcher.group(1);
            int val = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.format("parsed: %s , %d%n", txt, val);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this will still find a key/value pair on a line that is commented with `#`.