# Parse values from a string

Tags: java, regex, text-parsing

How would you parse the values in a string, such as the one below?

```
12:40:11  8    5                  87
```

The gap between numbers varies, and the first value is a time. The following regular expression does not separate the time component:

```
str.split("\\w.([:]).")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the file fixed-width delimited?

Comment: If you can explain why you think `"\\w.([:])."` would work, I can elaborate on where the logic went wrong. Right now I'm not even sure how you came to that.

Comment: what is the expected output? `[12,40,11,8,5,87]` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The regex `\s+` matches one or more whitespaces, so it will `split` into 4 values:

```
"12:40:11", "8", "5", "87"
```

As a Java string literal, this pattern is `"\\s+"`.

If you want to get all 6 numbers, then you also want to split on `:`, so the pattern is `\s+|:`. As a Java string literal this is `"\\s+|:"`.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Alternation with the Vertical Bar](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [Character Class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

---

#### On `Scanner`

Instead of using `String.split`, you can also use [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and [`useDelimiter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) the same as what you'd use to `split`. The advantage is that it has [`int nextInt()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) that you can use to extract the numbers as `int` (if that's indeed what you're interested in).

#### Related questions

- [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner/)

Comment: Yes, this is correct, "\\s+" works for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

See the [Pattern doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) and [String API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

Using

```
str.split("\\s+");
```

will yield

```
[ '12:40:11', '8', '5', '87' ]
```

or

```
str.split("\\s+|:");
```

should yield

```
[ '12', '40', '11', '8', '5', '87' ]
```