# Java How to loop until variable is equal to a specific type (String/int)

Tags: java

Hi I'm currently developing a small booking program, I'm curios to know if i can use a Loop to run until a variable is equal to a specific type, notably a String or An Integer. 
For example i have the following below, and I want the user to always enter a number.

If not, am i right in presuming i should just develop a try/catch etc.?

Regards.

```
  public int SetHouseNo(){   
  System.out.println();        
  System.out.print("Please enter your house number:   ");    
  HouseNo=in.nextInt();
  return HouseNo; 
  }
```

Comment: `String` and `Integer` are not primitive types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Thank you, pretty basic stuff so thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: When you say "I want the user to always enter a number" is it (a) you want the user to enter the same specific number every time or (b) you want to make sure the user enters a number and not some other string?

Comment: The user needs to always enter a number(Integer), and not say 'blah'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How to validate that the user entered an integer, without throwing or catching an exception:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (!sc.hasNextInt()) { // <-- 'peeks' at, doesn't remove, the next token
    System.out.println("Please enter a number!");
    sc.next(); // <-- skips over an invalid token
}

return sc.nextInt();
```

- [Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)
- [Scanner.hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)
- [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Comment: Thanks for that and the links, managed to adapt it to my code so now working perfectly, a really good way of doing it , need to wrap my head round precisely what's going on but works perfectly for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

Try/catch is overkill.  This is a job for do/while.

```
int house;
do {
  house = in.nextInt();
while (house isn't right for whatever reason);
```

Comment: There will be an uncaught `InputMismatchException` if the token is not an `int`.

Comment: Ah.  That _would_ justify a `try/catch`, but it sounded like the OP's issue was with the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use this simple loop:

```
public static int askForInteger(Scanner in, String msg)
{
     while (true)
     {
         System.out.print(msg + " ");
         String input = in.next();
         if (input.matches("\\-?\d"))
             return Integer.parseInt(input);

         System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't enter a valid number.");
     }
}
```

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux `parseInteger` isn't a method either. It's `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: @paislee: Omg, I was really confused. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

Change 6 to your "specific" variable (Assuming HouseNo is a public variable and initialized toa value different than 6 before entering the method.):

```
public int SetHouseNo()
{   
  System.out.println();
  while(HouseNo != 6) 
  {   
    System.out.print("Please enter your house number:   "); 
    try
    {  
       HouseNo=in.nextInt();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
  } 
  return HouseNo; 
}
```

Comment: @HertenFerford time lag? what is it?

Comment: @HertenFerford hmm ok. i hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Following the latest clarification in the question's comment, the question is more about checking a valid number (and not some other text) was entered, not that a specific number was entered.

Comment: There will be an uncaught InputMismatchException if the token is not an int

Comment: @paislee method returns houseNo, so it has to be defined as integer. when it comes to user input, you are right and i have added handling all exceptions.

Comment: @HertenFerford i have edited my code so that it can handle exceptions, for example user may enter a string while you are excpeting an integer. if the 10 minutes is done tick accept please :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to catch `InputMismatchException` from your reader if you want to allow numbers only. You could use a boolean to indicate whether you've found a suitable number or use auto boxing/unboxing and use a `null` value when no suitable value has been found:

```
Integer houseNumber = null;
do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Please enter your house number:");
        houseNumber = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        houseNumber = null; // Not actually necessary, but perhaps clearer
    }
} while (houseNumber == null);
```

Comment: @HertenFerford you don't _have_ to catch the exception, there is a standard approach for this. See my answer

Comment: @HertenFerford: I'd agree with this, paislee's and MartijnCourteaux's answers sound better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Some people aren't agreeing with this, but here's what I would do:

```
public int SetHouseNo(){   
    System.out.println();        
    System.out.print("Please enter your house number:   ");    

    try
    {
        HouseNo=in.nextInt();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number...");
    }
    return HouseNo; 
}
```

And then somehow, possibly in the place where you call the method, make a while loop or something so it keeps asking until you entered a number. If you want, of course...