# Extending java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, extends

Suppose I would like to add a method to Scanner called `nextPositiveInt()` which is similar to `nextInt()` except that when a negative integer is detected, a custom `InputNegativeException` is thrown.

Why would I want to do this when there are [solutions that utilise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner) `hasNextInt()`? While being a little less concise, it seems a whole lot tidier and more logical given the purpose of exceptions. For example:

**Extended Scanner method:**

```
Scanner cli = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean inputValid = false;

do
{
    System.out.println("Enter your age:");
    try
    {
        int age = cli.nextPositiveInt();
    }
    catch(InputNegativeException e)
    {
        System.out.println("You cannot specify a negative age.");
        inputValid = false;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Your input must be numeric.");
        inputValid = false;
    }
} while(!inputValid);
```

**`hasNext()` method:**

```
Scanner cli = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
    while(!sc.hasNextInt())
    {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    int number = sc.nextInt();
} while(number <= 0);
```

So assuming you aren't already firing up a response telling me why this is a very bad idea (if it is, please do; I imagine there might be some objection regarding putting validation in Scanner) I'm confused about how to go about this. I guess I need to replicate the body of `nextInt()` in `nextPositiveInt()` with some minor changes? Can you even source the body of `nextInt()` anywhere?

I apologise that I have no code to show any effort I've made but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought Scanner class is final and you cann't extend it there exist another solution. You can use [Delegation pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

Also as Scanner class has all nessasary methods public you can easily copy original method and  make a little change. See source code of Scanner class the only thing you should change is regexp used for matching string in order to exclude negative ints.

Source code of scanner:

```
public int nextInt() {
    return nextInt(defaultRadix);
}

public int nextInt(int radix) {
    // Check cached result
    if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Integer)
    && this.radix == radix) {
        int val = ((Integer)typeCache).intValue();
        useTypeCache();
        return val;
    }
    setRadix(radix);
    clearCaches();
    // Search for next int
    try {
        String s = next(integerPattern());
        if (matcher.group(SIMPLE_GROUP_INDEX) == null)
            s = processIntegerToken(s);
        return Integer.parseInt(s, radix);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        position = matcher.start(); // don't skip bad token
        throw new InputMismatchException(nfe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

You should change only:

```
String s = next(integerPattern());
```

For you purposes you can hardcode regexp. Original regexp can easily be caught on debug.

Definitely it wouldn't be the best solution in terms of realization - a lot of code to write and many copy-paste, but it would be easy and nice to use.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) since it's `final`:

```
public final class Scanner
extends Object
implements Iterator<String>
```

What I would do is have a helper method in one of my classes:

```
public static int ensureNonNegative(int val) {
  if (val >= 0) {
    return val;
  } else {
    throw new InputNegativeException(val);
  }
}
```

and would use it like so:

```
int val = ensureNonNegative(scanner.nextInt());
```

Comment: I saw that in another question - so the only way would be to have a `nextPositiveInt` method somewhere else? Not ideal but would work I guess.