# Asking for input after catching an exception

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, numberformatexception, inputmismatchexception

I want the user to enter a number which is scanned by the following code:

```
scanner.nextInt();
```

If a user enters a string instead, the program throws `InputMismatchException`, which is obvious. I want to catch the exception in such a way that the program prompts the user to enter an input until the user enters an integer value.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        //statements
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException ex ) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

This code creates an infinite loop if a string is entered.

Comment: You may need to reset the `Scanner` (I've no real experience with the class, but I've seen it done else where), try `scanner.reset()` before the `continue`

Comment: You might want to take a look at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);` within your `while` loop.

```
Scanner scanner;
while(true) {    
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        //statements
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException ex ) {
        System.out.println("I said a number...");
    }
}
```

Comment: what you said works but I have defined the scanner object out side the method itself. In other words, it's a class variable. Is there a way to do so without creating the object within the try-catch statement?

Comment: Of course, just reinstanciate the same object each loop. See the edit.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to my problem is as follows:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(input);
        //statements
        break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException ex ) {
        scanner.next();//new piece of code which parses the wrong input and clears the //scanner for new input
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
while(true) {    
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("\n\nEntered number is : " + input);
        break;
    } catch(InputMismatchException | NumberFormatException ex ) {
        System.out.println("\n\nInput was not a number. Please enter number again : ");
    } catch(Exception e ) {
        System.out.println("\n\nException caught :: " + e);
    }
}
```

I have also removed `continue` syntax as those are not needed.