# Validating a text against some rules

Tags: java, validation

I have a text and I need to validate it against the following rules:

1. The text must have a length of 8 characters
2. The text must have a leading letter
3. The text must have a trailing letter
4. The text must have 6 numbers between the 2 letters

A good example is:*L123456X* or *l123456x*

I did it the following way:

```
public boolean isValidated(String str) {
    boolean validated = false;

    char a = str.charAt(0);
    char z = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
    int i;
    if (str.length() == 8 && Character.isLetter(a) && Character.isLetter(z)) {
        validated = true;
        for ( i = 1; i < str.length() - 1; ++i ) {
            if(Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))) {
                validated = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return validated;
}
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Where are you checking your first rule: that the string has a length of `8`?

Comment: Try looking into regular expressions.  You should be able to match a single letter, at least six alpahnumeric characters, and one more letter with one regex pattern.  Something like `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}[a-zA-Z]$` - then use a regex matching method to test your string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner). The first answer mentions that Scanners are regex based, which agrees with the comments you already have on this question.

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]$`

Comment: @Robert I corrected it, please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java regular expression:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z][0-9]{6}[a-zA-Z]");

    System.out.println(p.matcher("L123456X").matches()); // true
    System.out.println(p.matcher("L12345X").matches()); // false

    System.out.println(p.matcher("1234567X").matches()); // false
    System.out.println(p.matcher("A1234567X").matches()); // false
}
```

If you want uppercase letters only. Use [A-Z][0-9]{6}[A-Z]

NOTE: We don't have to add ^ and $ as some developers often do (For java)

Comment: Your pattern matches a bit too much, eg. "shouldnotmatch123456X" is but should not be accepted. Abhi's comment on the OP rightly adds anchors (^ and $) to that pattern.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: We don;t have to add ^ and $. You can test it. If you pass shouldnotmatch123456X || 123456X || 1234567X -- > return false

Comment: You are right. When testing with the Pattern class, it returns false as intended. When writing the comment, I had crosschecked your pattern with Rubular, where it returned a match. Guess that's something to keep in mind. I'd still say that it's cleaner and closer to the letters of the OP's rules if you'd use anchors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to look at [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). All of your rules can be expressed in such expressions. Once you get the hang of that special syntax, you'll love it. Here's a [beginners guide](http://regexone.com/). Use [this](http://rubular.com/) to test your resulting expression.

Afterwards, you can test your input in a single statement by asking

```
Pattern.matches($your_expression, str);
```