# Getting a name as an input using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am a beginner in both, Java and regular expressions. I want to get a name as an input, by which I mean that only names that have English alphabets A-Z, case insensitive and spaces.

I am using a `Scanner` class to get my input but my code doesn't work. It looks like:

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
String n;

while(!sc.hasNext("^[a-zA-Z ]*$"))
{
    System.out.println("That's not a name!");
    sc.nextLine();
}
n = sc.next();
```

I checked my regular expression on the website [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com) and found out that it works fine.

For example, If I input it my name, `Akshay Arora` , the regex site says it is okay but my program prints

```
That's not a name
That's not a name
```

Same line is printed twice and it again asks me for input. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `.matches(regex)` is what you want to do!

Comment: I am referring to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner

Comment: Also your scanner object is `abc1` not `sc`. Also `scanner.hasNext()` returns boolean.

Comment: @UmaKanth, the third example of vowels uses regular expressions this way.

Comment: I have a scanner object `sc` defined at the top, just my mistake I left the `abc1`. Should delete that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts are wrong:

- `$` and `^` anchors are considered in the context of entire input, not in the context of the next token. It will never match, unless the input has a single line that matches the pattern in its entirety.
- You use default delimiters, which include spaces; therefore, `Scanner` will never return a token with a space in it.

Here is how you can fix this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
sc.useDelimiter("\n");
String n;

while(!sc.hasNext("[a-zA-Z ]+"))
{
    System.out.println("That's not a name!");
    sc.nextLine();
}
n = sc.next();
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/h9jJNm)

Comment: Great. This answers the question in the context in which it was asked.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this pattern allows arbitrary number of spaces which is not suitable for name checks

Answer (score 1):

Here its sample program related to regex.

```
public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String inputName = sc.next();

    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z ]*$";
    // Compile this pattern.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

    // See if this String matches.
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(inputName);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Valid Name");
    } else
        System.out.println("Invalid Name");

    }
}
```

Hope this will help you