# Scanner#nextLine() leaves a leftover newline character

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been running into a problem with Scanner#nextLine. From my understanding, nextLine() should return the rest of the current input stream and then move on to the next line.

```
while (true){
      try{
        System.out.println("Please enter a month in numeric form");
        month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a day in numeric form");
        day = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter a two-digit year");
        if (input.hasNextInt() == true){
          year = input.next();
        }
        else{
          throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
        }
        break;
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println(e);
        System.out.println("\nOne of your inputs was not valid.");
        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
      }
    }
```

The problem is the last line. If I leave it as input.nextLine(), the next iteration of the loop accepts a newline character for the month. Why is that? Shouldn't the call to nextLine in the catch block consume the rest of the line (including the newline) and prompt the user correctly in the next iteration? Note: I've decided to print them to try and figure out what's happening, but no cigar.

I've gathered some output from the terminal to illustrate what I mean:

```
// What should happen (this is when catch contains input.next() rather than nextLine)
    /*
    Please enter a month in numeric form
    8
    Please enter a day in numeric form
    2
    Please enter a two-digit year
    badinput
    java.util.InputMismatchException

    One of your inputs was not valid.
    badinput
    Please enter a month in numeric form <------------- prompts for input, as expected
    */

// What happens when I have nextLine in the catch block (code above)
    /*
    Please enter a month in numeric form
    8
    Please enter a day in numeric form
    2
    Please enter a two-digit year
    badinput
    java.util.InputMismatchException

    One of your inputs was not valid.
                                         <------------ leftover newline printed, as expected
    Please enter a month in numeric form <---------------- does not prompt for input due to another leftover newline (why?)
    java.util.InputMismatchException

    One of your inputs was not valid.
    badinput <----------------------- prints badinput even though it should've been consumed on the last iteration (why?)
    Please enter a month in numeric form
    */
```

Before someone marks this as a duplicate, please understand that I've looked at the differences between next and nextLine on stackoverflow already. nextLine should consume the newline character but it doesn't seem to do that here. Thanks.

Comment: `if (input.hasNextInt() == true){` is the same as `if (input.hasNextInt()){`. Why compare to true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (input.hasNextInt() == true) { // prefer `if(input.hasNextInt())`
    year = input.next();
} else {
    throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
}
```

for input `badinput` will evaluate `input.hasNextInt()` as false which means that `else` block will be executed without *consuming* that `badinput` (to do it we need to call `next()` - not `nextLine()` because as you probably know if we use `nextLine` after `nextInt` we will consume remaining line separator, not value from *next* like, more info at [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)).

So since else block simply throws exception it moves control flow to `catch` section. This means we are skipping `break` so our loop will need to iterate once again.

Now in catch section you are simply printing

```
System.err.println(e);
System.out.println("\nOne of your inputs was not valid.");
System.out.println(input.nextLine());
```

which prints exception `e`, string `"\nOne of your inputs was not valid."` and result of `nextLine()` (which as explained before) will simply consume line separators which remained after last `nextInt()` call, so we still didn't consume `badinput` from Scanner.

This means that when loop starts another iteration and asks for month, it receives `batinput` which is not valid `int` so `nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException`. And again we end up in `catch` block and we call `nextLine()` which this time consumes `badinput`.

Now since we finally consumed that incorrect value loop will start another iteration and we will be asked for value for month.

To avoid this kind of problems please read examples from: [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner). In first example you will find way to validate each input at time it is provided

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number!");
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number!");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }
    number = sc.nextInt();
} while (number <= 0);
System.out.println("Thank you! Got " + number);
```

To avoid writing this code many times create your own utility method. You can even skip condition where you require from number to be positive like:

```
public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String askMsg) {
    System.out.println(askMsg);
    while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("That's not a number. Please try again");
        sc.next(); // consuming incorrect token
    }
    //here we know that next value is proper int so we can safely 
    //read and return it
    return sc.nextInt();
}
```

With this method your code could be reduced to

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int month = getInt(input, "Please enter a month in numeric form");
int day = getInt(input, "Please enter a day in numeric form");
int year = getInt(input, "Please enter a two-digit year");
```

---

You can add another version of that utility method in which you can let programmer add conditions which number should pass. We can use IntPredicate functional interface for that added in Java 8, which will allow us to create conditions using lambdas like

```
public static int getInt(Scanner sc, String askMsg, IntPredicate predicate) {
    System.out.println(askMsg);
    int number;
    boolean isIncorrect = true;
    do {
        while (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
            String value = sc.next(); // consuming incorrect token
            System.out.println(value + " is not valid number. Please try again");
        }
        number = sc.nextInt();
        if (!predicate.test(number)) {
            System.out.println(number + " is not valid number. Please try again");
        }else{
            isIncorrect=false;
        }
    } while (isIncorrect);

    return number;
}
```

Usage:

```
int year = getInt(input, "Please enter a two-digit year", i -> (i>=10 && i<=99));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect when you are entering two digit year, and as you are using next() to read it so it will read the next string only. And it will leave 2 to be read by your nextLine() new line or empty value before even you enter the value for your 2 digit year and anything after that will be left over including the new line or carriage return as you entered an invalid value. So your nextLine() inside catch just reads that left over part of invalid input but leaves the new line or carriage return as is. which is causing the exception to occur while you expect prompt to appear to read month. you can place nextLine() after each nextInt() or next() to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the `Scanner` does not see your print statements, it just reads input as a *stream* of characters. The fact that you, as a user, enter those characters one line at a time is meaningless to the scanner.

So, you type `8<ENTER>` (where `<ENTER>` represents that actual newline character(s) of your OS). After `nextInt()`, the `8` has been consumed.

You then type `2<ENTER>`, making the pending input `<ENTER>2<ENTER>`. Remember, only the `8` was consumed, so far. `nextInt()` skips then whitespace and returns `2`, thereby *consuming* `<ENTER>2`.

You then type `badinput<ENTER>`, making the pending input `<ENTER>badinput<ENTER>`. Since the next token is not a valid integer number, you throw exception, and enter the `catch` block, where you call `nextLine()`. It consumes all character up to and including the first `<ENTER>`, and returns the text before, i.e. an empty string.

At this point in time, `badinput<ENTER>` is still pending in the stream, and is processed when you loop back.

---

**This is one of the main flaws in how people use `Scanner`.** `nextInt()` doesn't consume the line, only the token, leaving the rest of the line behind.

Example of how things go bad with `Scanner`:

```
Please enter a month in numeric form
8 2 17
Please enter a day in numeric form
Please enter a two-digit year
```

Because user entered all 3 values on the first line, you code will get the values, but will still print the next two prompts, even though that is unnecessary. It's just weird like that.

*Solution 1:* Don't use `Scanner`. It's just too dang weird. Too easy to use, and soooo easy to misuse, aka soooo difficult to use correctly.

*Solution 2:* Call `nextLine()` after each `nextInt()` to flush (silently consume) any extra text after the accepted value. If you do that, the example would go like this:

```
Please enter a month in numeric form
8 2 17
Please enter a day in numeric form
2
Please enter a two-digit year
17
```

The `<SPACE>2<SPACE>17<ENTER>` on the first line would be silently ignored.

You could extend the logic to `if (! nextLine().trim().isEmpty()) {/*ERROR*/}` if you want full error handling.