# Error Checking on certain codes

Tags: java

I did wrong explanation . Now I am doing better explanation. My problem is error handling that is not exception. So my code is below. Can I check wit try catch if I dont want to enter non-positive integer for example

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type in the expression with no empty spaces: ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();

    String[] tokens = split("[*,/,+,-");  

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        String delims = tokens[1];

        double n1 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[0]); 
        double n2 = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);

        switch(tokens) case1;"+"  System.out.println(n1+n2) // All cases
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to check whether expression is valid or not. `String` class provides `matches()` method to validate a string with Regex, e.g.:

```
String regex = "[0-9]+[-+/\\*][0-9]+";
String expression = "3+6"; 
System.out.println("3+6".matches(regex));
```

You can use `matches` inside an `if` condition to validate user's input. Once that is done, you can use 'split("\b")' to extract operands and operator.

**update**

The code after adding above logic will look like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = sc.nextLine();
String regex = "[0-9]+[-+/\\*][0-9]+";
if(s.matches(regex)){
    String[] tokens = s.split("\\b");
    //Your logic
}else{
    System.err.println("Please try in a valid expression!");
}
```

Comment: I have added an example.

Comment: dont need by mistaken I wrote previous assignment