# How to code into program using string from user input and making sure that it includes decimals?

Tags: java

I was wanting to make my program,in Java, In which it decides,based upon user input, if the input is a valid character. The valid characters consist of : numbers, and decimals. I must verify and make sure that these characters are not valid: + - .(must appear once only)
Code so Far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
//Makes Variables
    String z;
    int max;
// Scanner
Scanner Input =  new Scanner(System.in);
// Asks user to input the number    
System.out.println("Please enter a valid (4 character) double literal :");
//Accepts users input   
z= Input.nextLine();
  max = Integer.parseInt(z);
//Based on User input outputs
  if (max >= 0.0 & max <= 9.0) 
  {
      System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double literal");
      if (max>9.0){
          System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double literal");
          if(max<9.0)
          {
              System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double   literal");   
          }
      }
  }
//closes scanner
   Input.close();   
 }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Comment: Im kind of confused how this is a duplicate.

Comment: you can see a possible error directly if you format your code - `if(max>9) if(max<9) dosth()` will never evaluate as true

Comment: and if you want to parse a decimal number possibly containing a `.` I would recommend to use `Double.parseDouble` instead of `Integer.parseInt`

Comment: What is the point of those internal if statements.

Comment: i don't really know ,but as a new coder i am still learning. I fixed them to be outside

Comment: I need to make sure that I use Scanner,nextLine()
Also the Double Literall Needs to fit the following 4 requirements:
1. Consists of exactly the following characters: ’+’, ’-’, ’.’ (decimal point), and ’0’ through ’9’
2. Either the ’+’ or ’-’ character may appear only as the first character
3. The ’.’ (decimal point) character must appear exactly once
4. All other characters must be the ’0’ through ’9’ characters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse an unsigned decimal number, just do it with a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
double d = scanner.nextDouble();
if (d>=0) // valid
```

To only check that the input is valid, you could use a regular expression, like this:

```
if (Pattern.matches("[+\\-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?", z)) // valid
else // invalid
```

Comment: but i need an output to the user that their input is incorrect. Also need to check for + and - if the user enters them

Comment: @GugiD ok i added a detection for the sign to the regex. the scanner should automatically be able to handle this. if you want a feedback for the user just code it

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time understanding what you really want, but I assume you want the user to input a double between 0.000 and 9.999. If that is the case, then declare `max` as a `double` instead of an `int`. Along with that, instead of `max = Integer.parseInt(z);`, do `max = Double.parseDouble(z);`.

However, if you are validating the input length, then compare against `z.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have several problems on your code, first of all you have a piece of code that would never produce a conclusion so you should change:

```
        if (max>9.0) {
        System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double literal");
        if(max<9.0)
        {
            System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double   literal"); 
        }
    }
```

for :

```
    if (max>9.0) {
        System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double literal");
    }else if(max<9.0)
        {
            System.out.print(max+" is a valid (4 character) double   literal"); 
        }
```

And also you should declare the input as a double instead of a int

Comment: I have changed the coding and made max a double.

Comment: Ok, if you have any problem ask again