# Use scanner to read inputs next to a certain word

Tags: java

Here is an example of such input.

```
A 3 
B 1 
A 2 etc.
```

As shown above, each input is separated by a line and appears an indeterminate amount of times. 
How do I only read the numbers next to the 'A' and convert it all into a string using Scanner?

Comment: You mean [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3059367/2180785)?

Answer (score -1):

You can write something like:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main29 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String string = scanner.next();

            int number = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
3
1
2
```

As you can see I just write a loop which works until scanner can read token from STDIN. Inside of loop I read `String` tokens use `next` method and then read `Integer` tokens use `nextInt` method.

I think now you can add and required logic to the loop i.e. print numbers after A as you wish.