# Error Detection of non-numeric input

Tags: java

I am currently working on a program that requires answers to various math equations. I have the program working fine with displaying correct and incorrect based of the inputted numerical value. I am trying to add an extra aspect to the code that detects an incorrect input, and prompts the user that their input is in the incorrect format (ex. if the user inputs the letter a, the program displays "Your answer does not meet the correct format, make sure your answer is an integer"). I tried doing this through if statements but equal to (==) and not equal to (!=) only takes care of the numerical aspect. How do I go about this form of error detection in my code? Thanks for the help!

Here is my current code (I know its messy):

```
         Random random = new Random();
        int a = random.nextInt(10);
        int b = random.nextInt(10);
        int c = random.nextInt(4);
        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int f = 0;
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Would you like to choose your math problems, or random problems?");
          System.out.println("Input 'randomize' for random problems and 'choose' to choose your operator.");
             Scanner inputproblem = new Scanner(System.in);
             f =  inputproblem.nextInt();

             int randomize = 1;
             int choose = 2;


              if(f == 1){
                  System.out.println("What operator type would you like? (add,subtract,multiply,divide)");
                  Scanner operatortype = new Scanner(System.in);

                  int add = 0;
                   int subtract = 1;      
                   int multiply = 2;
                  int divide = 3;
                int  g =  operatortype.nextInt();
                    if (g == 0){
                      System.out.print("\t\t\t\tWhat is ");
                         System.out.print(a);
                        System.out.print(" + ");
                        d=a+b;
                          System.out.print(b+"?");

                          e =  input.nextInt();
                          input.close();

                         if (e == d){
                           System.out.print("\t\t\t\tCorrect!");

                         }

                         else if(e != d){
                        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tIncorrect.");
                System.out.println("\t\t\t\tThe correct answer is: "+d);

              }
                    else if (g == 1){
                      System.out.print("\t\t\t\tWhat is ");
                     System.out.print(a);
                    System.out.print(" - ");
                    d=a-b;
                      System.out.print(b+"?");

                      e =  input.nextInt();
                      input.close();

                     if (e == d){
                       System.out.print("\t\t\t\tCorrect!");

                     }

                     else if(e != d){
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tIncorrect.");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tThe correct answer is: "+d);

                    }
                    else if (g == 2){
                      System.out.print("\t\t\t\tWhat is ");
                         System.out.print(a);
                        System.out.print(" * ");
                        d=a*b;
                      System.out.print(b+"?");

                      e =  input.nextInt();
                      input.close();

                     if (e == d){
                       System.out.print("\t\t\t\tCorrect!");

                     }

                     else if(e != d){
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tIncorrect.");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tThe correct answer is: "+d);

                    }
                    else if (g == 3){
                      System.out.print("\t\t\t\tWhat is ");
                         System.out.print(a);
                        System.out.print(" / ");
                        d=a/b;
                      System.out.print(b+"?");

                      e =  input.nextInt();
                      input.close();

                     if (e == d){
                       System.out.print("\t\t\t\tCorrect!");

                     }

                     else if(e != d){
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\tIncorrect.");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\tThe correct answer is: "+d);


                    }
                    }

              else if (f == 2){
              System.out.print("\t\t\t\tWhat is ");
             System.out.print(a);
           //Switch that allows for the random generation of different math operators

             switch (c){
                case   0:
                        System.out.print(" + ");
                        d=a+b;
                        break;

                case   1:
                        System.out.print(" - ");
                        d=a-b;
                        break;

                case   2:
                        System.out.print(" / ");
                        d=a/b;
                        break;

                case   3:
                        System.out.print(" * ");
                        d=a*b;
                        break;

            }

          System.out.print(b+"?");
          e =  input.nextInt();
          input.close();

         if (e == d){
           System.out.print("\t\t\t\tCorrect!");

         }

         else if(e != d){
        System.out.println("\t\t\t\tIncorrect.");
System.out.println("\t\t\t\tThe correct answer is: "+d);

         }
```

Comment: At the bare minimum include your code.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to include all of your code, but how are you currently getting input from the user? Are you using Scanner.nextInt()?

Comment: Yes, I am using Scanner.nextInt().

Comment: @JamesT I also added my code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple decent ways I would go about this:

- Use Scanner.nextInt() and [detect if they gave a valid input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3059367/270483) (see example 1)
- Input a string from the user and check if it's valid by using [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Answer (score -3):

You're probably looking at `a.compareTo(b)`. Though I can't really tell since you didn't provide any code. If it returns anything other than `0` the input does not match.

Here's the [link](https://www.leepoint.net/data/expressions/22compareobjects.html) for a detailed explanation on the method.

**EDIT: the following is what you're looking for upon seeing your code**

If what you're looking for is simply restricting the input to either and `int`, `string`, or `double`. Just use a Scanner for the input and do `if(!scanner.hasNextInt()`, `if(!scanner.hasNextDouble()` and so on...

Comment: without seeing the code, your stab at an answer is wild speculation.