# INVALID INPUT AND LOOP

Tags: java

T student 
Im wondering if the user input a Character not an integer.How can i Show the word INVALID to him
and let him Type again.

EXAMPLE:

input a two number

a

INVALID try Again:1

2

Sum of two number=3

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0, y, z;

    System.out.println("Enter two integers to calculate their sum");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        x = in.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException e ) {
        System.out.print("INVALID");
    }

    y = in.nextInt();
    z = x + y;

    System.out.println("Sum of the integers = " + z);
}
```

Comment: you have to use a `while` loop and `break` out of it once the input is valid

Comment: [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3059333)

Answer (score 1):

You can do for example:

```
            while(true) {
                try {
                    x = in.nextInt();
                    break;
                  } catch (InputMismatchException e ) {
                    System.out.print("INVALID try again:");
                    in.next(); //To wait for next value otherwise infinite loop
                  }
            }
```

Basically you need to add the input into a loop and keep looping until you get valid input. You can write it in different ways but that should be the idea.

The in.next() in the catch is required because nextInt() doesn't consume the new line character of the first input and this way we skip to that.

If I were you I would use in.nextLine() for each line of parameters and the manipulate the String that I get to check for valid input instead of waiting for exception.

Comment: just use `break` instead of introducing a variable

Comment: There is a problem

Comment: Non stop INVALID try again:INVALID try again:INVALID try again:INVALID try again:INVALID try again:

Comment: ok I eddited it ;) I didn't actually test it I just wanted to give the idea. get the version now. You need to add one in.next() in order to move to next input

Comment: @Stultuske if the user input an character instead of a int.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov IT WORK THANK YOU VERY MUCH but can you explain it to me how the codes work?

Comment: added it in the answer