# Looping an else statement inside a for loop?

Tags: java

In this script, the user must input 5 numbers separated by new lines. The purpose is to check whether the input is an integer or not, and if it isn't, then it should theoretically **loop, asking the user to input a valid integer**.

The first part works - if the user inputs a value which isn't an integer, it throws the error and asks them to input a valid integer. But if they enter an invalid integer again, it throws an exception, which I don't want it to do. I want it to loop the else statement until the input is an integer.

I tried embedding a while loop within the else statement but it started getting messy and I couldn't figure out how to work it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
public class NumbersArray
{
    int[] numbers = new int[5]; // Defines new array string with length of 5 characters
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = numbers.length; // Defines length int, calculates how many in numbers int

    public void inputToNumbers()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) // Declares i as 0, while i less than length loop runs. Increments each time
        {
            System.out.println("Input five whole numbers, separated by new lines:" + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
            String inputtedNums; // Declares inputtedNums string
            inputtedNums = sc.nextLine(); // Inserts input
            if (inputtedNums.matches("[0-9]+")) // Checks if the input is numbers only
            {
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputtedNums); // Parses string input into integer numbers
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error! You inputted an invalid number, try again." + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
                inputtedNums = sc.nextLine(); // Takes user input
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputtedNums); // Parses string input into integer numberS        
            }
        }
    }

    public void printTheNumbers()
    {
        for(int x=0; x<length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println(numbers[x]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NumbersArray na = new NumbersArray();
        na.inputToNumbers();
        na.printTheNumbers();
    }
}
```

Comment: *I want it to loop the else statement until the input is an integer.* That is **not** possible, nor does it logically make any sense. Create a method to get the input. Don't return from the method until you have valid input. An infinite loop in that method, that only ends on valid input (for example).

Comment: inside your else, you need to put your code in a while loop. i.e. while the input is not a valid integer, keep asking

Comment: @Bentaye thank you that worked perfectly!

Comment: @josef you could also factor the input reading bit in a method that returns an int, and have the loop in that method to make the code easier to read.

Comment: @Bentaye I'm not sure what you mean by this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Bentaye you should write your comment as an answrr, so it can be a reference for future askers.

Comment: @josef I added an answer expanding on my comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating input using java.util.Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059333/validating-input-using-java-util-scanner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work fine.

```
public void inputToNumbers()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++) // Declares i as 0, while i less than length loop runs. Increments each time
        {
            System.out.println("Input five whole numbers, separated by new lines:" + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
            String inputtedNums; // Declares inputtedNums string
            inputtedNums = sc.nextLine(); // Inserts input
            while (inputtedNums.matches("^-?[^\\d]+$")) // Checks if the input is not number 
            {
                System.out.println("Error! You inputted an invalid number, try again." + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
                inputtedNums = sc.nextLine();

            }
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputtedNums);
            // Parses string input into integer numbers
        }
    }
```

My concern is that whether negative integers are allowed or not? I have included an optional negative number case. See working code here : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/fzy9sHCGtz

Regex Test : https://regex101.com/r/KKrpUu/1

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, you can simplify your code this way:

Create an other method just to read a number from the console input and you can then call it again until you get an actual number. This replaces looping with recursion

```
public void inputToNumbers()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[5];
    for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Input five whole numbers, separated by new lines:" + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
        numbers[i] = readNextnumber();
    }
}

private int readNextnumber() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputtedNum = sc.nextLine();
    if(!inputtedNum.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        System.out.println("Error! You inputted an invalid number, try again.");
        return readNextnumber();
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(inputtedNum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of @Bentaye, I added the following to my else statement:

```
        else
        {
            while(!inputtedNums.matches("[0-9]+"))
            {
                System.out.println("Error! You inputted an invalid number, try again." + " (" + (i+1) + "/5)");
                inputtedNums = sc.nextLine(); // Takes user input
            }
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputtedNums); // Parses string input into integer numberS        
        }
```

And this worked perfectly.