# How to write the java interpreter/lexical analyzer

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, data-structures, interpreter

How to write For 1 data type, integer, and the only identifiers are single letter (i.e. there are only 26 possible identifiers).

not case sensitive  have white space (blank characters, tab characters, and end of line characters) between every lexeme.[see this](http://pastebin.com/wzbHrK7m)

Comment: I've read the question, have read the link text and still can't understand what you mean. By the way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: typically with a lexical analyzer you read 1 character from the source file at a time then classify it, identifier, number, keyword, etc... Also have you tried anything? Just because you have grammar doesn't really prove you've done any work

Comment: writing program with switch cases for operators @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Write a program to read file . Here is a good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811851/how-do-i-read-input-character-by-character-in-java then have a hasmap of what integer value you want to assign to to your char.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great NLP engine called [**OpenNLP**](http://incubator.apache.org/opennlp/) written in Java.

Take a look over there code, you'll learn a lot.