# Truly Interactive command-line

Tags: java

Is there in Java the possibility to get what a user press "when it presses"
and not when he hits return?

So, for example, if a user hit ABC and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> I want that the program ends there
(end of stream reached) and not, after, when he presses return.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811851/how-do-i-read-input-character-by-character-in-java ?

Comment: You can create a gui application in which there is only lines, as so you can listen to the user interactions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read a single char from the console in Java (as the user types it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066318/how-to-read-a-single-char-from-the-console-in-java-as-the-user-types-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows doesn't actually end the stream when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>; you can continue to edit the line and the application will only see the end of the stream when you press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

This is slightly different to Unix where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will send the current buffered line to the application (without a newline) and the application will only perceive the end of the stream when you send an empty buffer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> either after a <kbd>Return</kbd> or after another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

**Edit**: On Windows, you might be able to use the [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033.aspx) function to allow you to read single characters. I'm not sure how you would call it though; there appear to be three choices:

1. Via JNI to a DLL that calls SetConsoleMode
2. Invoke a program that calls SetConsoleMode
3. Wrap your program in a launcher that calls SetConsoleMode
4. **Edit**: Use JNA to call SetConsoleMode.

Comment: Yes. Thanks but you answer only a part of my question. So is not possible with Java to detect a key when it's pressed?