# Compilation error: variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to create a method that adds to a variable for each character inside a file. If the file was:

```
abcd
abc
ab
```

then after the function ran the variable it would return would be equal to 9.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
public static double getRow(String filename) {
   double size = 0;
   File f;
   Scanner infile;
   try{
      f = new File(filename);
      infile = new Scanner(f);
   }
   catch (IOException e){
       System.out.println("Error opening the file");
       //System.exit(0); not good
   }
   while(infile.hasNext()) {
       size++;
   }
   infile.close();
   return size;

}
```

But I keep getting that `infile` has not been initialized. I'm not sure how to get the solution I want.

Comment: All the code after the catch block down to the close (inclusive) should be inside the try block. Don't write code like this.

Comment: NB The scanner probably won't do what you want. Just read lines with a `BufferedReader`, and add up their lengths.

Comment: How should I use it versus what I have right now?

Comment: Err, the way I just said?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initializing `infile` in the `try` block, if anything goes wrong in the `try`, `infile` will never be initialized when you attempt to use it after the `catch` block.

What you want to do is having all you processing in the `try` block, included looping through and closing `infile`:

```
public static double getRow(String filename) {
    double size = 0;
    File f;
    Scanner infile;
    try {
        f = new File(filename);
        infile = new Scanner(f);
        while(infile.hasNext()) {
            size++;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening the file");
        //System.exit(0); not good
    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to add up all the characters in the file?

Comment: As mentioned by EJP, have a look at `BufferedBeader`, or just search for `java read file character by character`, you will find plenty of examples. Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811851/how-do-i-read-input-character-by-character-in-java, but there are many others.

Comment: Reading character by character won't work. It will count the line terminators, whatever they are.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this; the error is "variable infile might not have been initialized", which is because if there's an exception in the line `new File`, it wouldn't have been.

There are several solutions, but the best would be to make sure you don't try to use `infile` if you're not guaranteed it's been initialized, for example by putting the code inside the `try` block as above.

Here's my version:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Foo {
    public static double getRow(String filename) {
        double size = 0;
        File f;
        Scanner infile ;
        try{
            f = new File(filename);
            infile = new Scanner(f);
            while(infile.hasNext()) {
                size++;
            }
            infile.close();
            return size;

        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error opening the file");
            //System.exit(0); not good
        }
        return -1;
    }               

    public static void main(String[] argv){
        System.out.printf("ResultsL %d\n",
                          getRow("foo.txt"));

        return ;
    }
}
```

Ideally, you'd also make this a `public static int` with `int size=0;`, because you're counting something, which is a discrete value, not a real.

Comment: VG but why public? and static? Why a member?