# Checking parenthesis balanced in each sentences ending with dot ('.')

Tags: java

I'm writing java code for test balanced parentheses in source code.

Here is the code for check balanced parentheses .
In main

```
  String s = reader.nextLine();
    System.out.println(process(s));
```

My function

```
public static boolean process(String s) {
    Stack<Character> stack  = new Stack<Character>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(c == '[' || c == '(' || c == '{' ) {     
            stack.push(c);
        } else if(c == ']') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '[') {
                System.out.println("yes");
                return false;
            }
        } else if(c == ')') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '(') {

                return false;
            }           
        } else if(c == '}') {
            if(stack.isEmpty() || stack.pop() != '{') {

                return false;
            }
        }

    }
    return stack.isEmpty();
}
```

It look ok if I only use test case with single line.

```
input1 : abctex()[]
output: true
```

Now I got problem, how can check balanced parentheses in each sentences with last index is dot ('.').

For example
Input

```
So when I die (the [first] I will see in (heaven) is a score list).

[ first in ] ( first out ).

Half Moon tonight (At least it is better than no Moon at all].

A rope may form )( a trail in a maze.

Help( I[m being held prisoner in a fortune cookie factory)].

([ (([( [ ] ) ( ) (( ))] )) ]).

 .

.
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
false
true
true
```

Answer (score 2):

You external loop should be not by lines but by sentences. That is read everything up to the dot and use that as input to `process`. Repeat until the end.

You can read char-by-char like this [How do I read input character-by-character in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811851/how-do-i-read-input-character-by-character-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But my input simply from keyboard, not from file.

Comment: It does not matter where you read from. `System.in` is `InputStream` which you can use the same way as `FileInputStream` in the answer I linked.